# Append binary data to serialized xml header

Tags: serialization, encoding, binary, jaxb

I need to append binary data to file but before this data is an xml header. Whole file wont be proper xml file but it must proper xml header like following:

```
<EncryptedFileHeader>
    <Algorithm>name</Algorithm>
    <KeySize>256</KeySize>
    <SubblockLength>64</SubblockLength>
    <CipherMode>ECB</CipherMode>
    <sessionKey>sessionKey</sessionKey>  
</EncryptedFileHeader>
*binary data*
```

The xml header I do with JAXB marshalling easily, and even easier would be to add this *binary data* in base64 and store in note inside xml. But this is a clue. I have to store it as binary to save this overhead 33% space used by base64.

So the question is **how to add this data and of course later read this back (serialize/deserialize) ?**

Another question is **how to remove  from the first line of document?**

I tried to use:

```
marshaller.setProperty("com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration", Boolean.FALSE);
```

but it throws an exception:

*javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: com.sun.xml.bind.xmlDeclaration value: false
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractMarshallerImpl.setProperty(AbstractMarshallerImpl.java:358)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.setProperty(MarshallerImpl.java:527)*

Thanks

Comment: You can use the standard `JAXB_FRAGMENT` property instead.

Comment: You may find the following helpful:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/jaxb-web-services-and-binary-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualy I solved this by serializing xml header with JAXB, then appending binary data (bytearray) to existing file. 
Reading from file with buffered reader as follows:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filepath"));
        String line, results = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            results += line;
        }
        reader.close();

        String[] splited = results.split("</EncryptedFileHeader>");
        splited[0] += "</EncryptedFileHeader>";
        String s0 = splited[0];
        String s1 = new String(splited[1]);
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(s0.getBytes());
```

Now i got a problem with second splited string s1, which consist data from "byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();". Now I have to transfer data from this string to byte array. From:

'��A����g�X���

to something like:
[39, -63, -116, 65, -123, -114, 27, -115, -2, 103, -64, 88, -99, -96, -26, -12]

I tried (on the same machine):
byte[] bytes = s1.getBytes();

but bytes array is different and returns 34 bytes instead 16. I read a lot about encodings but still have no idea.

EDIT:

**The problem with different number of bytes was due to the different representation of new line by character and byte streams.**